# Uploading multiple images no longer working after updating from django 3 to 4

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Django project I recently updated to version 4.2 I am experiencing an issue where a ClearableFileInput i had that allowed a user to upload multiple images no longer works throwing the error

```
ValueError: ClearableFileInput doesn't support uploading multiple files.
```

I have looked at the updated documentation and it seems `multiple` has changed to `allow_multiple_selected`  however when i use this like `'images': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'allow_multiple_selected ': True}),` I am only able to upload only a single image.

form:

```
class PostImagesForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = PostImages
    fields = ('images',)
    widgets = {
        'images': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'allow_multiple_selected ': True}),
        
    }

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['images'].required = False
```

view:

```
    @login_required
def createPostView(request):

    postForm = PostForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        postForm = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        postImages = PostImagesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
   
        #has to be 21 as it includes the cover img
        if len(request.FILES.getlist('images')) >= 21:
                messages.error(request, 'More than 20 image gallery images uploaded')
                return render(request, 'blog/post_form.html', {'postForm': postForm, 'PostImagesForm':PostImagesForm})
                
        for image in request.FILES.getlist('images'):
            if image.size > settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE:
                messages.error(request, f'Image gallery image {image} is too large 10mb max per image')
                return render(request, 'blog/post_form.html', {'postForm': postForm, 'PostImagesForm':PostImagesForm})

        else:        
            if postForm.is_valid():
                PostFormID = postForm.save(commit=False)
                PostFormID.author = request.user
                PostFormID.save()                       
                if len(request.FILES.getlist('images')) == 0:
                    return redirect('post-detail', PostFormID.pk , PostFormID.slug)
                else:
                    for f in request.FILES.getlist('images'):      
                        postImages = PostImagesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
                        if postImages.is_valid():
                            instance = postImages.save(commit=False)
                            instance.post_id = PostFormID.id
                            instance.images = f
                            instance.save()   
                return redirect('post-detail', PostFormID.pk, PostFormID.slug)
            
               
    return render(request, 'blog/post_form.html', {'postForm': postForm, 'PostImagesForm':PostImagesForm})
```

Comment: Same problem here. Anyone found a workable solution, now Django 3.2 LTS is getting EoL from April onwards?